# Change main page of TabbedPage, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I want to set the **Heart screen** as the **first** shown page when entering the whole TabbedPage, I would be happy if anyone can help me with that.
Thanks

**Each icon is a blank content page title:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the current page as the page you want in the construction method of the tabbedpage. Such as:

```
public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CurrentPage = Children[2];
    }
```